# Array field not being recognized as attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, attributes, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following model I created,

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :location_type
      t.integer :location_id
      t.integer :categories, array: true, default: '{}'

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :user, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

I've also added the pg array parser gem to my Gemfile.

The issue is that whenever I create a user, it tells me that categories is an unknown attribute.

```
User.create(name: "Bob", email: "bob@gmail.com", 
password: "password", password_confirmation: "password", categories: [1, 2])

The Error:

unknown attribute: categories
```

What's wrong and how can I fix this?

Update:

After running `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` I came across this new error.

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "categories" is of type integer[] but default expression is of type integer
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Comment: Have you checked your `users` table in PostgreSQL? A simple `\d users` from `psql` will tell you what the table really looks like.

Comment: I didn't see a categories field in the `schema.rb` so I reset the database. Results are shown in the answer.

Comment: Have you tried `default: []` or `default: "'{}'::integer[]"? The old postgres_ext gem for Rails3 properly casts `'{}'` to `'{}'::integer[]` but maybe Rails4 is getting confusing and doing `'{}'.to_i` instead.

Comment: Thanks @mu. Using `default: []` works. Post it as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`postgres_ext`](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext) gem for adding array support to Rails3 understands that `default: '{}'` means that the SQL should say `'{}'::integer[]` but I'm guessing that the Rails4 driver is getting a little confused and saying `'{}'.to_i` or something like that; sorry, I don't have Rails4 set up anywhere so I can't be more specific but it does match the error you're seeing.

You could try using a Ruby array instead of the PostgreSQL-style array-string:

```
t.integer :categories, array: true, default: []
```

That will trigger the right to-sql-ification with `postgres_ext` so it should do the Right Thing in Rails4 too.